# Group by column. If null, group by other column

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In entity framework I'm working with a table with a self-referencing column that was created like so and I can't change this structure because it's already being used too many places in the project:

```
Entities
--------
CreationDate         | EntityID | OriginalEntityID |    Name
2014-01-02 10:02:02  |   819    |        NULL      | First draft
2014-02-05 14:04:20  |   899    |        819       | Second draft
2014-05-16 02:45:40  |   907    |        819       | Third draft
2014-05-16 02:45:40  |   908    |        NULL      | Other entity
```

Then there's another table that's like so:

```
EntityValues
------------
EntityValueID | Value | EntityID
       1      |  20   | 819
       2      |  30   | 899
       3      |  25   | 899
       4      |  12   | 907
       5      |  20   | 908
       6      |  99   | 908
```

I need to do a group by in entity framework that will group by so that the example data above will return two groups of values like so:

```
Values
------
  20
  30
  25
  12
```

AND

```
Values
------
  20
  99
```

**Is there any way to even do this in entity framework? Basically, group by `OriginalEntityID`, but if that's null then group by `EntityID`.**

I don't know where to start so there's not much code I could have tried.

In my actual code I'm looping over the individual values in a group and doing a linear regression on the entire group, then comparing all the groups against each other. I'm debating just looping over all the data points (rows) individually and from there figure out what group they belong to. Performance isn't really a priority here because I have a separate processes running this stuff overnight so it's ok if it takes a while.

Comment: Can you try `group foo by foo.OriginalEntityID ?? foo.EntityID` using the null-coalescing operator to express your requirement? I don't know if that will be translated into EF, but it's worth a try

Comment: @JonSkeet I was making a big change in the application so I had to write an isolated test from scratch. Yes, the null-coalescing operator works perfectly for this! I forgot about using it in EF because EF is kind of limited to what you can use with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) works for Entity Framework as well.

Example:

```
db.EntityValues.GroupBy(v => v.Entity.OriginalEntityID ?? v.Entity.EntityID);
```